# Xcode/Swift multiple collectionview in scrollview with different orientation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

So my main problem is that I have 3 collectionview in a scrollview, my first two collection view is horizontal, but my last collectionview is vertical, and I'm trying to nest it in the scrollview. I've tried to make the last collectionviews constraint to 0 from bottom, but that messed up the whole layout.

---

The result should be like in Android when I set the Recylcerviews scrolling to false and nested scrollview to true.

---

Any idea how I can make this work ? or should I use something else?

Comment: can you send images what you have & what you want

Comment: Did you give Height constraints to all 3 collection views?

Comment: Try putting them in a stack view.

Comment: Provide images of what you want achieve & write some code that you've tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying out multiple approaches, I find a way that works for me.

I've put a view inside my scrollview with constraints(0,0,0,0) and set the view height to the height of the content above the vertical collection view...
Then I've set my vertical CollectionView bottom constraint to 0

Declared the height constraint of my view in my controller

The last step was to calculate the height of the CollectionView after loading the data and add it to the height constraint of my view . for example  if the height of my vertical CollectionView cell is 250 and I've fetched 4 items from database, then I have to add 4x250 to the height constraint of my view like:

```
mViewHeight.constant += 1000
```